# How to get the results of a queryset to display as a subsection within a another class-based list view

Tags: python, django, templates, django-queryset

Need help / advice with Django.
I have two apps with models.

- App1 *Player* with Model *player*
- App2 *Competition* with models *Competition* and *Team* the latter being a through table expanding on the *Player* table
- Players can be assigned to multiple Competitions
- Each competition has a Team via a through table expanding on the Player table

Extracts of models below

Player and Competition have class based list and detail views

In the Competition detail view I would like to list all Players for that particular competition.

I can only get as far as proving the principle on the command line

```
>>> comp_one = Competition.objects.get(name="comp one")
>>> comp_one.team_members.all()
<QuerySet [<Player: Armstrong>, <Player: Smith>, <Player: Jones>]>
```

Then as a novice I’m a bit lost

1. how to perform the queryset on the current competition rather than hard coded competition name
2. where to put the queryset function - views.py or models.py
3. how to get the Team listed in the competition detail template

```
class Player(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nick_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["last_name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.last_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(“player_detail", args=[str(self.id)])
```

```
class Competition(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    team_members = models.ManyToManyField(“players.Player”, through=“Team")

    class Meta:
        ordering = [“date"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(“competition_detail", args=[str(self.id)])


class Team(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    player = models.ForeignKey(
        “players.Player”,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    mission = models.ForeignKey(
        “Competition",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

Any advice greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can create an active bool field for all your competitions and query based on "active" competition.

```
Competition.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('id')
```

And lastly `order_by('id')`. So you get all in linear/sequential order. Hope it helps you or gives you some way to find a better approach